# Migrar código MySQL 5.6 a SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

Necesito pasar este fragmento de código que esta en código MySQL 5.6

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('2010-06-01', INTERVAL 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2010-06-01',CURDATE()) YEAR), INTERVAL   
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2010-06-01',CURDATE())) - 
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2010-06-01',CURDATE()) * 12) MONTH)) AS DIAS
```

a SQL server pero no se cómo, no estoy familiarizado con MySQL.

Con este `SELECT` lo que pretendo es obtener los dias transcurridos entre dos fechas, pero no un `DATEDIFF` de dias.

El `SELECT` devuelve un numero entero de `0` a `30`, ya que si pasa dicho intervalo, se sumara tiempo pero en meses. No se si fui claro, espero que si.

Comment: creo que esto sirve [sitio conversor](http://www.sqlines.com/online)

Comment: el sitio que le recomiendas lo he probado y le deja exactamente la misma estructura

Comment: Si, yo tambien probé. Estuve mirando y TIMESTAMPDIFF equivale a DATEDIFF en SQL server, y DATE_ADD a DATEADD, pero no se usar este ultimo, ya que esa parte de INTERVAL no se como se "traduce"

Comment: pero incluso esta sintáxis en mysql tienes errores

Comment: Tenes razon, por ahi habia un parentesis al comienzo que estaba afectando

Comment: Revisa la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) para que se te haga más fácil traducir el lenguaje.

Comment: en tu pregunta también deberías anexar que deseas obtener exactamente e igual pudieras recibir mas y mejor ayuda

Comment: No suele ser bien recibido por la comunidad un pregunta que solo tiene código, te sugiero que expliques un poco que es lo que hace el mismo para tener un poco más de contexto.